# How do I specify a "larger than" image size in the Google Custom Search API?

Tags: google-custom-search

I am using the Google Custom Search API to find images.

In the API call I can specify image sizes like Small, Medium, Large, X Large, XX Large, Huge.

But I want images that are X Large and upwards. For example, if I select the X large option I don't want to exclude images that are classified as XX Large and Huge.

I can't figure out how to ask for multiple image sizes selections in the API call, and I can't find an option to define "images larger than" which would also solve my problem.

Any ideas?